# Matlab surf angle variation

Tags: matlab, plot

I use a 2D `surf` to plot the phase information of a signal. My two matrices that define the two axis XY are between -360, 360 deg.

Is it possible to tell to surf to plot between 0, 360 without normalise the matrices?

Because I need this correction only inside the surf plot and I don't want to undo the operation once the plot is drown.

As you see it goes between -360 and +360. The information is the same, but the plot appears like this, using two different colours to represent the same thing. I know that surf plots what it sees, but I hope I can avoid useless computations just to normalise these two matrices just to plot this thing and then de-normalise them again.

```
surf(radtodeg(X),radtodeg(Y),(radtodeg(angle(Z1))-radtodeg(angle(Z2))),'edgecolor', 'interp');     %Sum pattern 3D
    view(2);
    xlabel('\theta_h'); ylabel('\theta_v');
    grid on; colorbar;axis square; 
    xlim([-100*BW 100*BW]);
    ylim([-100*BW 100*BW]);
```

Where `radtodeg` is a simple function that I wrote to convert from radians to degree
[image]

Comment: Please provide the code that is used to create this figure.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with MATLAB's `rad2deg` :)

Comment: No way...I had no idea that there was already a function lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just

```
angles=yourangles;
angles(angles<0)=360-angles(angles<0)
surf(x,y,angles)
```

or even easier (Thanks @Dev-iL)

```
surf(x,y,mod(yourangles,360))
```